# Slack app global shortcuts not showing after app installation

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have created a Slack app, enabled interactivity for it, declared global shortcuts for it, declared a `commands` scope for it, and installed it into a workspace with a OAuth request that included the `commands` permission. However, by the end of the process, even though the app is listed in the "Apps" section of the target workspace, the declared shortcuts still weren't listed in the "Shortcuts" dropdown. Is there anything I'm missing here? It's worth noting that the app's current distribution status is "Needs revision to resubmit to App Directory"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app is published in the Slack App Directory. This means that any new changes you make to your app need to be reviewed and approved by Slack's app directory team before they propagate. Likely explains why you're not seeing the shortcut.